# How to set width and height to a richtextbox and do not grow rather hide overflow

Tags: lexicaljs

I'm using Lexical with React, when use same logic as shown on playground I can see the size of the richtextbox is determined by how big my toolbar is. If I don't want a toolbar, where should I set a width and height for initial richtextbox?
And is there API I can use to update those later?

Another related question is how can I set it to be fix size without auto-grow? I want to see if it can hide the overflow, or stop user from typing

Be able to update the textbox size.
Be able to change to not grow.

Answer (score 0):

you could set the max-height of *.editor-input* the in the css

```
.editor-input {
  min-height: 350px;
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  ...
}
```